# Java Service In Webmethods

Tags: java, integration, webmethods, java-service-wrapper

I wrote a java service in webmethods to open any folder in windows explorer but it wasn’t working as expected. When I debugged the code it was working fine but when i ran the service it wasn’t working. Can someone help me here

I want to open any directory with a java service in Webmethods.
package Java_Services;

```
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
        String  FilePath = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "path" );
        
        File openfile = new File(FilePath);
        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
            {
                //Desktop.getDesktop().browseFileDirectory(openfile);
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(openfile);
                //d.open(openfile);
            }
            else {}
        }
    
        catch (IOException e) 
            { }
        
    pipelineCursor.destroy();
```